# How do I Getting a TextField to do simple math?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have three UITextFields. Two of them represent a certain number value. The third represents the percentage of the two. How do I setup the 3rd UITextField to do this simple math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the intValue or the floatValue or the doubleValue of the text that you have received from the first two text fields. Eg:

```
float firstFloat = [self.firstTextField.text floatValue];
float secondFloat = [self.secondTextField.text floatValue];
float answer = firstFloat / secondFloat; //or whatever math you need to do

self.thirdTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",answer];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @TWcode This is right way to get your method. Or if u want to get percentage of another two text value then apply simple maths formula.

Comment: This works great! I'm still trying to adjust the readout to look like ...67.8%. What do I need to do?

Comment: Still having problems trying to display 78.9%. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure. You want to take the "answer" and then multiply by 100 to get the percentage. Then you need the last line to be self.thirdTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",answer]; The double %% is used to display a % sign in your output.

Answer (score 2):

Check out "Getting Numeric Values" here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

So you can use that to convert from the `text` property of your two `UITextField` instances.

Then you can convert them back to an `NSString` and plug them into the text of the third `UITextField` by using `initWithFormat` (something like `[initWithFormat:@"%d", theResult]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in the following way.

```
NSString *str1,*str2;
str1=text1.text;
str2=text2.text;
int num1=[str1 intValue];
int num2 =[str2 intValue];
int ans=num+num2;
text3.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ans];
```

Hope this helps.

```
[answer setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.02g", answerFloat]];
```

Comment: I've set it up to do a percentage. How can I get the readout to look like this: 87.8%

Comment: try using floatValue instead of intValue

Comment: I'm trying this "%.2f" along with the floating value still not looking right.

Comment: u mean while displaying the answer in the third textfield ?

Comment: Yes. My current readout looks like this 0.84 I need this to look like 84.0 %

Comment: Try the above code...I have added some code in the above answer...Hope that helps....